# I am trying to swap a word from the text to a word of my choice

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function replacment() {
            let text = document.getElementById('text')
            let button1 = document.getElementById('text')
            let button2 = document.getElementById('text')
            let text3 = text.replace(new RegExp(text1, 'g'), text2);
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text3
           }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="text">Steve Jobs was genuis, and many Apple inventions today are result for his great effort, thanks Steve, waw Steve was great.</h1>
    <label>search for:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="button1" />

    <br />

    <label>Replace with:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="button2" />
  <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Replace"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to swap a word from the text to a new word that I type in the second box.
In the first box I want to type in a word from the text above that will be changed
I am using HTML and JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `HTML` is parsed from top to bottom. So when you use

```
document.getElementById("text")
```

It would return null so you can't set properties on null. Because at the time of this statement the element doesn't exist.
So to solve the problem

- put `script` tag just before the closing `</body>` not in the `<head>` tag.
- other option is to listen to the **DOM** has been loaded with `DOMContentLoaded` & `addEventListener` or simply with `window.onload`.
- **BUT** With the arrival of the [`defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) we can place the `script` in the *head* and still, get that benefit while also having the JS be downloaded by the browser in parallel with the HTML for better performance.

  ```js
  document.querySelector("#replaceBtn").addEventListener("click", replacment);
  function replacment() {
      let text = document.getElementById("text");
      let searchWord = document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
      let replaceWith = document.getElementById("replaceTxt").value;
      console.log(text, searchWord, replaceWith);
      text.innerText = text.innerText.replace(
      new RegExp(searchWord, "g"),
      replaceWith
      );
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h1 id="text">
      Steve Jobs was genuis, and many Apple inventions today are result for his
      great effort, thanks Steve, waw Steve was great.
  </h1>
  <div>
      <label>search for:</label>
      <input type="text" id="searchTxt" />
  </div>
  <div>
      <label>Replace with:</label>
      <input type="text" id="replaceTxt" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Replace" id="replaceBtn" />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let text = document.getElementById('text').textContent
let input = document.getElementById('input')


input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let newtext = text.replace('steven', input.value);
    document.getElementById('text').textContent = newtext
})
```

```html
<h1 id='text'>hello world my name is steven i love programming</h1>

    <input id='input'>
```